# Missing header files using embedded C test environment

Tags: c, embedded, signal-processing

I am currently working on my project wherein I need to program a DSP processor for a modem to do binary FSK modulation. The system was earlier using a QPSK modulation. I have use the same infrastructure, only need to modify the frequency modulation technique. The DSP processor is simulated using a set of C files on a LINUX machine and all the code is tested out on LINUX before moving on to the actual device.

Right now I have just started with the programming and I am just trying to compile my current codeset. I am facing a lot of issues with missing header files.

The device infra files use the header files like:

- filter.h,
- sysreg.h,
- builtins.h

Now I am getting all these headers as "file missing" errors. I was able to fix a couple with

```
#include <sys/reg.h>
#include <linux/filter.h>
```

But the builtins.h file is still missing and I am not able to compile the code.

I am using UBUNTU 11.10 and gcc version 4.6.1. Is there some special set of files that I need to update for programming with embedded C. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: What's the problem?  You might need to be a little more specific than 'Now I am getting all these headers as "file missing" errors.' because this is unclear.

Comment: Sorry about the lack of clarity . The thing is for the builtins.h file, I am getting the following error :

**"fatal error: builtins.h: No such file or directory"**

I just wanted to know, if I need any special set of packages to be installed on my system for using embedded C programming, as I am just using GCC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`builtins.h` is a header that is part of the compiler project and specifies which functions are, literally, built-in to the language, according to the gcc docs.

Your problem is that the compiler you're using cannot find this file.

You have two options:

1. The first, assuming everything else is set up correctly, is to run `find /usr -name "builtins.h"` to locate the file and add that directory to the include (`-I/path/to/dir`) path.
2. If the system uses some form of cross compiler, make sure you're using that, rather than your host's gcc. If you aren't using the correct toolchain, I suspect you'll have problems linking, too.

Comment: Thanks man .... Even I felt the same that the system would be using some form of specific cross-compiler, specific to the DSP processor being simulated....